# Knockout-Validation library in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript, knockout-validation

I was just wondering whether anyone has had any luck in converting the knockout-validation plugin (https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) into coffeescript.

I have tried myself by using tools like http://js2coffee.org/ and so far I have been unable to get a version working in coffee.

I ask as the the project it is being used in is all written in coffeescript, and so when it comes to writing custom validation rules, the team are wanting to write them in coffee rather than javascript.  So far the custom rules have just been added to the knockout-validation javascript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the library as JS and write your own rules in CS, e.g.:

```
ko.validation.rules['validUKPostcode'] = 
  validator: (string) ->
    /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i.test(string)
  message: 'Please enter a valid UK postcode'

ko.validation.registerExtenders()
```